# What is the running time of the code snippet

Tags: algorithm, runtime, time-complexity, pseudocode

can someone help me in finding the run-time complexity of the following code snippet?

please help me in finding the run-time complexity of the code snippet given above.

Comment: what is the value of `n` in the first while loop statement? are you sure there is a `;` after the first while statement? I guess the code you shared has problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your code has problem, specially in the first while loop.

```
while (i <= n);
```

Having a semicolon after a `while loop` statement means, there is no statement under the loop statement. For your information, this while loop will run infinitely because you are not updating the loop variable `i`.

In case you have mistakenly put that semicolon, then the while will iterate `n` times which will make the time complexity for that while loop as `O(n)`.

But the time complexity of your second while loop is `O(log n)` because you are decreasing the loop variable `j` by halving the value.

```
while (j > 0)
    y := x/(2*j);
    j = j /2; 
    i = 2 *i;
```

So, in total if you consider both the while loops, then total time complexity should be `O(n + log n)` which is equivalent to `O(n)`.